# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has been destroyed in Android 13

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, crash, fragmentmanager

Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has been destroyed (Android Kotlin)

I got this crash on my firebase crashlytics for my app, and it happens too many times. The statistic shows that the crash is 97% happens to Android 13. And this crash is very confusing because I can't reproduce it. Someone said that this crash is from the library that I used because it was outdated, but again I can't make sure if it was. Did someone know how to handle this, or at least know how to reproduce it? Here is the crash logs

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has been destroyed
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1641)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1695)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:564)
       at com.github.terrakok.cicerone.androidx.AppNavigator.applyCommandsSync(AppNavigator.kt:34)
       at com.github.terrakok.cicerone.androidx.AppNavigator$applyCommands$1.run(AppNavigator.kt:29)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8741)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69890970/9290612

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager has been destroyed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60641206/java-lang-illegalstateexception-fragmentmanager-has-been-destroyed)

Comment: @A.R.B.N  I did tried that but again how to test that, cause I still don't know how to reproduce the bug

Comment: @AndreyBienkowski I did tried that but again how to test that, cause I still don't know how to reproduce the bug